# How can I "unwrap" a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm currently adding custom label controls dynamically at runtime in my WPF app.

I've got a WrapPanel wrapping the contents of the labels if needed(contents are set dynamically).

Everything works fine, but I want to "unwrap" the label.

The premise is that you can click and drag this label elsewhere on the screen (drag and drop functionality isn't the issue here) which is a much larger area and therefore should only occupy one line.

What would be the best way to achieve this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest** way to go about this is to use an ItemsControl for your dynamic list and change its ItemsPanelTemplate on the fly. Here is full working code I just made...

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="200">
<Window.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="wrapPanelTemplate">
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="stackPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource wrapPanelTemplate}">
         <ListBoxItem Content="TESTTEST " />
        <ListBoxItem Content="TESTTEST " />
        <ListBoxItem Content="TESTTEST " />
        <ListBoxItem Content="TESTTEST " />
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Change Template Button"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ItemsPanelTemplate stackPanelTemp;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stackPanelTemp = (ItemsPanelTemplate)(this.FindResource("stackPanelTemplate")); 
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemsControl.ItemsPanel = stackPanelTemp;
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How could I do this to only one label at a time?

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern or not in your application?

Comment: Yeah, using MVVM with the help of Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: Kinda tough to explain...
For your "custom label", create a VM and bind Text or whatever properties to the VM.
Create an ObservableCollection of that VM.
Then wrap the label in a DataTemplate and use the DataTemplate inside the ItemsControl, and bind the ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection of VMs.
After that you can add/remove VMs from the ObservableCollection and changes will be automatically reflected in the UI.